# Adding Google Adsense in a website privacy policy

Tags: google-adsense, personal-website, privacy-policy

I am making a privacy policy and for Google Analytics have this as a point which was suggested with a free privacy policy maker:

```
Personal Data Collected: Cookies and Usage Data
```

They did not have Adsense without paying a subscription charge which i currently don't want to do.

What would the point for Adsense be, perhaps simply the same as Analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of the requirement from AdSense on a Privacy Policy is not analytics, but cookies (the DoubleClick cookie) and opt-out information.

More information on what AdSense requires you to have in the Privacy Policy can be found in the terms agreement, at [Section 8](https://www.google.com/adsense/localized-terms):

[image: Terms section 8 from Google AdSense via TermsFeed]

As we mentioned in our [blog post here](https://termsfeed.com/blog/privacy-policy-google-adsense/), according to Google **your Privacy Policy needs to reflect your use of AdSense:**

- That Google uses cookies to serve ads to visitors of your website
- That the DoubleClick cookie used by Google allows Google to show ads to visitors based on their visit to your site and/or other sites (interest-based advertising)
- How users can opt-out from the use of the DoubleClick cookie for interest-based advertising